# dplyr : mutate and find next business day?

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr, lubridate

I have the following dataframe

```
time <- seq(from =ymd("2014-02-24"),to= ymd("2014-03-20"), by="days")
df2 <- data.frame(time)
df2 <- df2 %>% mutate(day_of_week = wday(time, label = TRUE))
> df2
         time day_of_week
1  2014-02-24         Mon
2  2014-02-25        Tues
3  2014-02-26         Wed
4  2014-02-27       Thurs
5  2014-02-28         Fri
6  2014-03-01         Sat
7  2014-03-02         Sun
8  2014-03-03         Mon
9  2014-03-04        Tues
10 2014-03-05         Wed
11 2014-03-06       Thurs
12 2014-03-07         Fri
13 2014-03-08         Sat
14 2014-03-09         Sun
15 2014-03-10         Mon
16 2014-03-11        Tues
17 2014-03-12         Wed
18 2014-03-13       Thurs
19 2014-03-14         Fri
20 2014-03-15         Sat
21 2014-03-16         Sun
22 2014-03-17         Mon
23 2014-03-18        Tues
24 2014-03-19         Wed
25 2014-03-20       Thurs
```

Is it possible to use `dplyr` and `mutate` to get the **next-business day** for every date in time? Say the next Monday if time is a Friday.

`lubridate` does not seem to handle business dates.

Many thanks!

Comment: Including holidays?

Comment: if possible, yes!

Comment: Quick and dirty: `df2 %>% mutate(next_biz_day = case_when(.$day_of_week == 'Sat' ~ .$time + 2, .$day_of_week == 'Sun' ~ .$time + 1, TRUE ~ .$time))`, but see chron's `is.holiday` and `is.weekday`

Comment: thanks @alistaire! can you write up a small snipped that works with the above example and `chron` ? I dont want to hard code the condition

Comment: Or if you want the next day even if it is a weekday, `df2 %>% mutate(next_biz_day = if_else(day_of_week == 'Sat', time + 2, time + 1))`.

Comment: With chron, something like `df2 %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(next_biz_day = min(time + (1:7)[!chron::is.weekend(time + 1:7)]))`

Comment: Oops, the second version should be `df2 %>% mutate(next_biz_day = case_when(.$day_of_week == 'Fri' ~ .$time + 3, .$day_of_week == 'Sat' ~ .$time + 2, TRUE ~ .$time + 1))` to handle Fridays correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(bizdays)

load_rmetrics_calendars(2014)

mutate(df2, 
       nbd_time=following(time_seq, 'Rmetrics/NERC'),
       nbd_time=ifelse(nbd_time==time_seq, offset(time_seq, 1, 'Rmetrics/NERC'), nbd_time),
       nbd_time=as.Date(nbd_time, origin="1970-01-01"),
       nbddow=wday(nbd_time, label=TRUE))
```

You can define/load precise calendars that account for regional differences or specific calendar needs.